# Page transition jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie to jQuery and developing an app in jQuery mobile.I am using page transition=slide or page transition=flip property of JQM for my pages but it is not working in chrome.Instead of giving transition to a page I want to do transition to a website.Please help me in this regards.

My code is

```
<a href="www.google.com" data-transition="flip" 
   data-direction="reverse">abc</a>
```

Comment: <a href="www.google.com" data-transition="flip">abc</a>

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pvDKW/1/)

Please go through this link for further details [Transitions](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html)

```
<div data-role="page" id="index1">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content">   <a href="#index" data-transition="flip">Click Me</a>    
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Page transitions only work for AJAX loaded pages (typically other pages in the same html file or other html files in your mobile website).

If you are actually leaving the site to another website, you cannot use the transitions.

Depending on what you are actually doing, you could transition to another local page that has an IFRAME, and just show the external site in the IFRAME. But note that not all sites allow themselves to be viewed within frames.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hzTfS/1/)**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index1">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>INDEX</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <a href="#index" data-transition="flip" class="ui-btn">Go to website</a>    
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>External Website</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <iframe id="theframe" src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/" width="100%" height="400px">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can load the IFRAME page as a dialog, and you can size the IFRAME to the device, etc.

Comment: You mean, if I want to embed any external link in my page using data -transaction it should be in iframe?

Comment: @ScorpionRulz, I am not giving you a hard and fast rule, simply suggesting one workaround depending on your needs. Do you want to leave your site? Do you want to show an external site within yours? Does that site prevent itself from running in frames? How badly do I need transitions?  Look at your requirements and decide on the best course of action.